# How to log specific user executed queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am wanting to keep a table log history of executed MySQLI queries and log the specific user who executed a query and date & time the query was executed - ***on any (all) of my PHP pages.***

**What is the best way and simplest way to achieve this?**

**PHP**

```
session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }

$connection = mysqli_connect("****", "****", "****", "****");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $accountNo = $_GET['ID'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
```

**Recommendation from a SO user:**

> However, there are errors with this suggestion ...many.

```
    $query = "UPDATE usertable set firstname = '".$firstname."', surname='".$surname."', dob='".$dob."', email='".$email."', phone='".$phone."', address='".$address."', town='".$town."', postcode='".$postcode."' where accountNo='".$accountNo."'";

    $log_action = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if($result) {

define("LOG_FILE", "https://www.*******.com/logfile.txt");
function log_action($action, $data) {
    $time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $user = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : '';
    $message = "$time\tuser=$user\taction=$action\tdata=$data\n";
    file_put_contents(LOG_FILE, $message, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Comment: You can write your own wrapper library around the mysqli functions, and have it log everything it's doing.

Comment: @Barmar I have other 50 PHP pages, would that require amendments to every MYSQLI query on each PHP page?

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing built-in that does this.

Comment: What do you mean by wrapper library? I am new to PHP to be honest, but learn't a fair bit since starting @Barmar

Comment: `my_mysqli_query()` logs a message then calls `mysqli_query()`. Similar functions for all the other mysqli functions that you want to log.

Comment: @Barmar - I could just just write a query that inserts into a table named log in my PHPMyAdmin db, with one column being Query and it storing  the query as string ?

Comment: @George - I would recommend setting up a trigger in MySQL - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107174/mysql-log-the-query-executed-on-certain-table

Comment: @blupointmedia How would a MySQL trigger know who the user is? It's a PHP session variable presumably.

Comment: Yes a PHP session @Barmar

Comment: So the it would insert the user session , and the query they executed , along with date and time stamp

Comment: @Barmar sorry I overlooked he was wanting to log the user as well. That won't work with triggers.

Comment: I am using procedural, I know its not recommended but at this moment in time, my website has over 50 PHP pages, I don't have time to amend the code. 

I believe my thought would work in what I am trying to achieve - Its just limited to only inserting the query, I can't really insert the original datafrom X table as old_data in the log table and then the new data being inputted in e.g. new_data.... it will just print to table the executed query

Comment: This thing is chock full of **extremely serious SQL injection bugs** so you're going to have to go through this code very carefully and fix tall those calls anyway before someone exploits one of these and "fixes" your site for you. As a note, most PHP ORMs ([RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) being just some examples) will do some kind of logging for you out out of the box, among many other things, like migration management.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate the input, and agree. However, that answer does not solve the predicament I am currently in. My hosting provider did not even provide a php.ini file, that I had to write myself. There is no logging to which I have access too, hence why I want to keep a log, a more detailed one - that being storing the user who executed the query (PHP session)

Comment: Turn on [general query logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) on your server and then fix these problems immediately. Anyone with even half a clue as to what you're doing here could crack this wide open in seconds. If you need user-level logging you can work that in more comprehensively, but honestly `mysqli` is a terrible interface. At the least use PDO if not an ORM. Converting is annoying, but the pay-offs in terms of productivity and *not being vulnerable to SQL injections* are huge.

Comment: @tadman -  Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation - hosting provider is restricting me

Comment: Not sure how you're logging to an `https://` "file" in this case, either. Just open a regular-old log file in append mode, then write to it as you would anything. A quick and dirty hack here is to wrap all your `mysqli` calls, but this just fossilizes this already extremely risky code. A re-write is unavoidable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a wrapper library that logs all the `mysqli` calls that you want to record, e.g.

```
function my_mysqli_query($link, $query, $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
    log_action('mysqli_query', $query);
    return mysqli_query($link, $query, $resultmode);
}
function my_mysqli_prepare($link, $query) {
    log_action('mysqli_prepare', $query);
    return mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
}
...
define("LOG_FILE", "/path/to/logfile.txt");
function log_action($action, $data) {
    $time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $user = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : '';
    message = "$time\tuser=$user\taction=$action\tdata=$data\n";
    file_put_contents(LOG_FILE, $message, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

I've written it to log to a file. You could log to a database table instead, it's just more code in `log_action()`.

Then do a global replace in all your other scripts, replacing `mysqli_query` with `my_mysqli_query`, `mysqli_prepare` with `my_mysqli_prepare`, and so on. So your code would look like:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $accountNo = $_GET['ID'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $town = $_POST['town'];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];

    $query = "UPDATE usertable set firstname = '".$firstname."', surname='".$surname."', dob='".$dob."', email='".$email."', phone='".$phone."', address='".$address."', town='".$town."', postcode='".$postcode."' where accountNo='".$accountNo."'";

    $result = my_mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if ($result) {
        echo "Update successful";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't write to a URL, it has to be a local pathname.

Comment: even if I just do logfile.txt .... it doesn't save anything  - as all of my files are in the same area (public_html) - and I believe there are some issues with that example, if you look at my procedural code. I believe its not saving anything - not because of the path but the actual function as I have done SERVER ROOT for a save path of session lifetime (ini_set) that works fine.

Comment: furthermore having  `log_action('mysqli_prepare', $query);` produced errors so I had to change it to  `$log_action($connection, $query);` and $action & $data...what are them variables even storing?

Comment: That makes no sense. log_action doesn't do anything with the database, why does it need $connection?

Comment: `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: Are you sure the webserver userid has write permission to the log file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190266/discussion-between-george-richardson-and-barmar).

Comment: @Barmar OP seems to be completely missing the point of your answer:  `$log_action = mysqli_query($connection,$query);`

Comment: @Barmar - Thanks, I fathemed the error , it was my behalf, your example works.